# форма, не работает кнопка отправить

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Есть форма:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

мне нужно ввести телефон, для отправки смс сообщения, я нажимаю на кнопку отправить, но нечего не происходит, почему не срабатывает кнопка отправить?

код формы

```
 <div class="main">

        <div class="container">
            <form method="POST" id="signup-form" class="signup-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3>
                    Номер телефона
                </h3>

                <fieldset>
                    <form >
                    <h2>Получение электронной карты</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="tel" name="tel" id="phone" placeholder="Ваш телефон" />
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded m-b-40" />

                </fieldset>


                <h3>
                    Код сообщения
                </h3>

                <fieldset>
                    <h2>Введите код сообщения</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="socials_twitter" id="socials_twitter" placeholder="Код сообщения"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <h3>
                    Персональные данные
                </h3>
                <fieldset> 
                    <h2>Персональные данные</h2>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="your_name" id="your_name" placeholder="Your name"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="your_phone" id="your_phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" name="your_addr" id="your_addr" placeholder="Address"/>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>

    </div>
```

ajax скрипт отправки

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("form").next(function() { //Change
            var th = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sms.php", //Change
                data: th.serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Done Functions
                    th.trigger("reset");
                }, 1000);
            });
            return false;
        });

    });
</script>
```

скрипт формы(далее, назад)

```
(function($) {

    var form = $("#signup-form");
    form.steps({
        headerTag: "h3",
        bodyTag: "fieldset",
        transitionEffect: "fade",
        labels: {
            previous : 'Назад',
            next : 'Вперед',
            finish : 'Отправить',
            current : ''
        },
        titleTemplate : '<div class="title"><span class="title-text">#title#</span><span class="title-number">0#index#</span></div>',
        onFinished: function (event, currentIndex)
        {
            alert('Sumited');
        }
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `$('#signup-form').on('submit', (e) => {`  - Так попробуйте.

Comment: А что это за событие next?

Comment: Ну и `var th = $('#signup-form').serialize();`   И ее передаете.

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev не сработало(

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko выше добавил скрипт

Comment: @fermeg А какую ошибку-то выдает?

Comment: А что за плагин steps?

Comment: @NikolayGabaraev ошибка быстро пропадает( так что только скриншот https://prnt.sc/q1rynz

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko https://colorlib.com/etc/bwiz/colorlib-wizard-20/index.html вот

Comment: Сделайте serialize отдельно, как я написал, а затем в data, передайте так - data: {"th": th};  - тогда ловить переменную будете как $_POST['th'] . Ну и скорее всего это выдаст ошибку, но уже новую)

Answer (score 1):

next не является событием. Fieldsets не привязаны к форме. метод next проходится по всем экземплярам указанного селектора, но это вам не нужно, вам просто нужно вызвать сериалайз у главной формы, он соберет в кучу все ваши формы.

```
console.log($("form").serialize());
```

Можете попробовать это, чтобы убедиться.

```js
    function SendForm(){

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sms.php", //Change
                data: $('form').serialize()
            }).done(function() {
                alert("Ваше сообщение отправлено");
                setTimeout(function() {
                    // Done Functions
                    $('form').trigger("reset");
                }, 1000);
            });
       }
       $('ваш сабмит').click(function(){SendForm()});
```

Comment: Ваша функция next не находит формы, вот и вся беда. Если я правильно понял, что вы хотели, этот код вам подойдет.

Comment: а мне, необразованному, подскажите:  если мы таким образом отправим POST запрос, как мы его поймаем в скрипте, если явно не указали его имя?

Comment: serialize формирует строчный запрос к серверу вида nameofinput=''&nameofinput=''

Comment: чтобы поймать достаточно $_POST['nameofyourinput']